# How do I debug a GraphQL resolver in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, debugging, graphql, resolver

I'm following a tutorial on [howtographql.com](https://www.howtographql.com), which creates a very basic GraphQL server with in-memory data and resolvers written in JavaScript. I keep having issues where I'd like to be able to just put a breakpoint in the resolver, but when I'm running the GraphQL playground GUI, I can't see anything in the DevTools' Sources panel, and putting a `debugger` line in the code doesn't stop it either.

How do I debug my resolver?

**Schema**

```
type Mutation {
  updateLink(id: ID!, url: String, description: String): Link
}
```

**Resolver** (I'm using immutable.js's Map; perhaps not correctly)

```
let links = [
  {
    id: "link-0",
    url: "www.howtographql.com",
    description: "Fullstack tutorial for GraphQL",
  },
]

const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    updateLink(root, args) {
      const linkIndex = links.findIndex(link => link.id === args.id);
      const state = links.map(link => {
        debugger;
        if (link.id === args.id) {
          const map = Map(link);
          return map
            .set("url", args.url || link.url)
            .set("description", args.description || link.description);
        }
        return link;
      });
      links = state;
      return state[linkIndex];
    },
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resolvers run on the server. The servers' code will not appear in DevTools' Sources panel. You have to use a NodeJS debugger from your IDE to debug your resolvers

Comment: Thank you! I'm using VS Code, so it was as simple as creating a launch.json! I should have known how to do this now that I think about it, but I'm a newb at server-side node, so it didn't occur to me.

Comment: You can write console.log() in your node code to debug.

Comment: Here is a tool that lets you debug the server side, https://graphql-debugger.com/ you can use it to view things that would otherwise be inaccessible in the browser like the context, errors, and resolver timing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Auto Attach from VS Code:

1. Follow the official doc to setup: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach
2. If you select "onlyWithFlag", you will need to launch with `node --inspect index.js`, the file `index.js` is where you start the server
3. Set a debug point in your resolver
4. Open local GraphQL explorer and run some queries, you will see the debugger is attached